# PlayOnLinux Equivalent for windows

Tags: windows-7, playonlinux

Like the PlayOnLinux do we have a similar application in windows that allows us to run a Ubuntu application on Windows OS.
Or is there any simulator to run the ubuntu terminal in Windows(for learning purpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use a virtual machine with a Linux Operating System?

You can use [VirtualBox by Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or [VMware player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/). They are both free, and allow you to create a Virtual Machine, which essentially is a virtual computer inside your computer, acting like a normal program, and running anything a physical computer with the same operating system can run (with the exception of games).

**[EDIT #1]:** I found some interesting tutorials on how to install Ubuntu inside VirtualBox [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox). It should help you to get started if you decide to follow this route.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

> Cygwin is:
>
> a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows.
>
> Cygwin is not:
>
> a way to run native Linux apps on Windows.
>
> You must rebuild your
> application from source if you want it to run on Windows. a way to
> magically make native Windows apps aware of UNIX® functionality like
> signals, ptys, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can install virtual box on your system. [What is virtual box?](https://www.virtualbox.org)
How to install it:

- [download virtual box (windows version).](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- [install it.](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox)
  Then you can load your Ubuntu OS in that and learn.[Visit this for extra information.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/User_HOWTOS)

Comment: You are actually giving him wrong information. He is on windows, he can not `apt-get install` anything there...

Comment: oh! sorry I forgot!!!!

Comment: I am extremely sorry about this.... i got to be more careful!